Send file Twilio Whatsapp API
I'm trying to send various file types (images, videos, documents) using Twilio's WhatsApp integration. While my proxy works perfectly for images, it fails for videos and documents, returning a format mismatch error in Twilio logs.
I'm trying to send a file along with my integration with Twilio for WhatsApp. I created a template that receives a URL which is a proxy, for example, https://myurl.com/proxy-file?file={{6}}. The proxy then returns the file to be sent via WhatsApp. It works very well with images, but it doesn't work when it's videos or documents, despite Twilio stating in the template creation that it is supported.
Imagem Twilio Template
Here is my proxy implementation:
app.get('/proxy-file', async (request, reply) => {
        const { file: fileUrl }: any = request.query

        if (!fileUrl) {
            reply.status(400).send('File URL is required')
            return
        }

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(fileUrl, {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            })

            let contentType = 'application/octet-stream'
            if (fileUrl.endsWith('.pdf')) {
                contentType = 'application/pdf'
            } else if (fileUrl.endsWith('.doc')) {
                contentType = 'application/msword'
            } else if (fileUrl.endsWith('.docx')) {
                contentType =
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
            } else if (fileUrl.endsWith('.mp4')) {
                contentType = 'video/mp4'
            }

            reply.header('Content-Type', contentType).send(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            reply.status(500).send('Erro ao obter o arquivo')
        }
    })

But when I check the Twilio logs, it gives me this error, even when I send a PDF, for example.
Twilio Error: [This message send failed because it violates Channel provider's policy. Please see Channel specific error message for more information.] - Whatsapp Error: [msg=header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received VIDEO, code=132012]

What exactly is your question? Does the mentioned 'Channel specific error message' give more information?

@ruud The issue is that Twilio says it accepts several formats in the template, but when I send a video or PDF this happens.

I just double-checked and it definitely works with all the filetypes you mentioned above. I assume there might be an issue with your webserver. Try to find a public URL that exposes and PDF or MP4 and use that to verify. Then, I'd suggest to debug your server to find out why it might behave differently.
